# Can't install libpng because it conflicts with earlier version

Tags: centos, software-installation, rpm, libraries

I'm trying to install SDL2_image-2.0.1-5, which seems to be the latest version of SDL2_image, based on rpmfind.net.  (The machine is CentOS, latest version, running on VMware on a 64-bit Windows box, and the package versions I'm getting are the latest on rpmfind.net for Fedora Rawhide, x86_64 versions). It complains of two failed dependencies

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    libpng16.so.16()(64bit) is needed by SDL2_image-2.0.1-5.fc26.x86_64
    libpng16.so.16(PNG16_0)(64bit) is needed by SDL2_image-2.0.1-5.fc26.x86_64
```

libpng-1.6.29-1.fc27.x86_64.rpm, the latest I can find on rpmfind.net, should provide these, according to the page there... but when I try to install it, I get a conflict.  It seems to be only about man pages, but I don't know:

```
warning: libpng-1.6.29-1.fc27.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, 
key ID f5282ee4: NOKEY
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
    file /usr/share/man/man5/png.5.gz from install of libpng-2:1.6.29-1.fc27.x86_64 
    conflicts with file from package libpng-2:1.5.13-7.el7_2.x86_64
```

`yum install libpng.x86_64` says

```
Package 2:libpng-1.5.13-7.el7_2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

so I'm confused about what to do.  (And does "Package 2" mean anything?)

`rpm -qi libpng.x86_64` tells me the package is not relocatable, FWIW.

Comment: What distribution/version? You might fare better if you chose a package that was created for your distribution/version. I'm guessing this one isn't.

Comment: I've got CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)  running on VMware.  So it's Red Hat -- if that's what you're asking.  The packages I've been loading are for Rawhide, which is (I think) the latest Fedora version.

Comment: Well, the libraries can live next to each other; only the `man` pages collide. If you don't care for the man page, you can remove one of them. Maybe `yum` doesn't even check for the conflict if you remove the file from the earlier installation.

Comment: Hmm. I have no idea what SDL is, and I'm not a RH user, but is it possible to rebuild the source RPM on your platform? With some suitable munging of the build dependencies if necessary? That's often a less painful route to follow.

Comment: I'd be willing to try to remove the man pages.  Is there a way to do that cleanly -- or do I just rm them?

Comment: Wrt your libpng conflict, it is possible to simply remove the older package without breaking any dependencies?

Comment: No, it complains that lots of things depend on it and refuses to remove it.  I suppose there's a way to override that, but...

Comment: Renaming the man pages didn't have any effect, but I wonder if I was indeed installing the wrong version.  Rawhide is the latest Fedora, but the libpng package with `fc26` is having a conflict with an older one with `el7_2` (Enterprise Linux, which CentOS uses). I am currently taking out all the Rawhide versions and trying to get it going with Enterprise.

Comment: That seemed to work!  Thanks, Faheem!  I will come back later and verify it's all copacetic.

Comment: It did work.  Everything's installed.  If you want to post your first comment as an answer, I'll accept it.  To be specific, I was using the latest Fedora, RawHide, and should have been using the one CentOS uses, which is Enterprise Linux.  The hint was the "fc26" not matching the "el7" in the .rpm files.

Comment: Hi @TopologicalSort. I'm not sure if you are addressing me, but if you are, what first comment are you referring to, please? Just to be clear. And note that users are not notified of comments unless you include a @ followed by the appropriate username to the comment. I just happened across this question again by accident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by the user, the problem was fixed by using packages/RPMs built for his system, CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core).

Apparently these correct RPMs were Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7 packages.

The difficulties he was earlier experiencing, as described in the question, were because he was trying to install Fedora Rawhide packages on his system.